# Swift: Keyboard behaviour. Why 'touchesBegan' not minimise keyboard when using scrollView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have been **manipulating keyboard behaviour** **for better user experience** when using my apps. (i.e. **minimising the keyboard** when tapped outside of a textfield.)

However, whenever I use **ScrollView** as the backdrop for any objects on the ViewController in Storyboard, I am unable to close keyboard using the following code...

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This code normally works fine whenever I DO NOT use ScrollView in the background, but not "with" it.

Instead I have had to resort to adding extra code with UITapGesture to create the same effect...

e.g. In...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I have had to add the following **1st**...

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddingViewController.dismissKeyBoard))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) // to Replace "TouchesBegan" - not work here.
```

Then a function...**2nd**...

```
func dismissKeyBoard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Thus doubling up on my workload when previously all I needed was `touchesBegan`

**Can anyone let me know why this is? Why does the presence of ScrollView have this effect?**

*(note: I am trying to understand the issue, as when I originally faced the problem, it caused a fair amount of frustration until I found the solution that worked by 'trial and error')*

Comment: looks interesting :) the interaction between UIScrollView, the touch system, gesture recognizers, the -hitTest: based event handling mechanism, touch cancelling and the actual call of the -touchesBegan method... can be confusing. Maybe the `keyboardDismissMode` property of UIScrollView will work?

Comment: Do you think scrollview & touches began, just conflict with each other and precedence is given to the scrollview as the bigger player in viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the scroll view is tapped. Try this:

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

If you want the scrollView to still be able to scroll, then don't add this; just add the tap gesture to the scroll view.

```
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: tap gesture has already been identified as the solution in the question, however, I am looking for the why, scrollview can't work with touches began? Or maybe there isn't a reason and the two are just incompatible?

Comment: This is because touchesBegan occurs when the view is tapped. If the scrollView is tapped, then Xcode thinks that the scrollView may be scrolling.